# Filter docker-compose output

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I have several containers that give many hundreds of lines of output when I do a docker-compose up and load all my services. Is there a way to filter that output easily or better yet, not have those services output to standard out, when doing docker-compose up?

Comment: You could try piping output through grep. Do you want those services to not output to standard out, or not capture their output at all? If not at all, you can set their logging driver to [none](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/).

Comment: You can set a logger in the compose file, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use detached mode when you start your docker compose

```
docker-compose up -d
```

If you want to see the logs of your containers, you can do:

```
docker-compose logs <name of your service that was defined in docker-compose file>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only `docker compose up`, it's possible to filter logs to specific services by using `--attach` or `--no-attach`.

**Example**

```
docker compose up --attach <service>
```

[See Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/#:%7E:text=The%20docker%20compose%20up%20command%20aggregates%20the%20output%20of%20each%20container%20(like%20docker%20compose%20logs%20%2D%2Dfollow%20does).%20One%20can%20optionally%20select%20a%20subset%20of%20services%20to%20attach%20to%20using%20%2D%2Dattach%20flag%2C%20or%20exclude%20some%20services%20using%20%2D%2Dno%2Dattach%20to%20prevent%20output%20to%20be%20flooded%20by%20some%20verbose%20services.)

Answer (score -1):

```
docker-compose up <service>
```